# disable or make non clickable form when spinner appears in css/html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have `bootstrap` form with `spinner`. Spinner appears when user submits form. It works fine, spinner appears on top of form, however, I cannot make `form` to be `disabled`/`not-clickable`, like usually it is with overlay.

```
form {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<form method="post">
  <div class="overlay" id="loading" >
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner-border" role="status" >
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="num">Enter number <span>?</span></label>
    <input id="num" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added one parent div to .overlay div and positioned it.

Hope this helps!

```css
form{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.overlay-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay" id="loading" >
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status" >
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="num">Enter number <span>?</span></label>
    <input id="num" type="text" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems that form is not clickable, but is it possible also to make it withis ome opacity or somehow visually so that user can see that it is not clickable?

Comment: just add  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) to overlay-container and that should do the job.